# Prove that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4}\ dx = \Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)!$ using the gamma function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, gamma-function

> Prove that $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4}\ dx =
>  \Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)!$$
>
> using the gamma function
>
> $$\Gamma(z+1) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{z}\ dt$$

I have a solution in my notes that does:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^4}\ dx = \frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty e^{-u}u^{-3/4}\ du = \cdots$$

what kind of substitution is this?

Comment: Simply $u = x^4$.

Comment: are you serious? as stated in you notes $x^4\rightarrow u$, so....?!

Comment: @tired yes. If $x^4= u$, then $du = 4x^3dx$ then $dx=du/(4x^3)$. Then what?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs
$x=u^{1/4}\rightarrow x^3=???$

Comment: So the downvotes and the close votes are because the question is trivial ?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Why not write $x=u^{1/4}$ first, then differentiate that with respect to $u$?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Because Guerlando didn't make enough efforts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution performed is just $u=x^4$.
$$u=x^4 \iff \color{blue}{x=u^{1/4}} \iff \color{red}{dx=\frac{1}{4}u^{-3/4}~du}$$
Hence:
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{\color{blue}{-x^4}}~\color{red}{dx}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{\color{blue}{-u}}\cdot \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}u^{-3/4}~du}=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-u}\cdot u^{-3/4}~du$$
The integration limits stay the same during the substitution since $x=0 \implies u=0$ and $x\to \infty \implies u\to \infty$.

---

You can continue the problem by identifying the value of $z$ on the definition of the gamma function, then using the following identity:
$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$